# Failed to pull image, unauthorized: authentication required

Tags: cloud-automation-manager

Trying to deploy CAM chart version 2101 from ICP 2101.  Deploy fails with the error:

> Failed to pull image
>   “mycluster.icp:8500/default/orpheus-iaas:2.1.0.1_121317”: rpc error:
>   code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get
>   https://mycluster.icp:8500/v2/default/orpheus-iaas/manifests/2.1.0.1_121317:
>   unauthorized: authentication required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scott mentioned, updating the image scope to global is the correct answer. This can be accomplished with a single command:

```
root@icp-master-1:~# kubectl get image -n=<namespace> -o yaml | sed 's/scope: namespace/scope: global/g' | kubectl replace -f -
image "cam-broker" replaced
image "cam-busybox" replaced
image "cam-mongo" replaced
image "cam-orchestration" replaced
image "cam-portal-api" replaced
image "cam-portal-ui" replaced
image "cam-redis" replaced
image "cam-service-composer-api" replaced
image "cam-service-composer-ui" replaced
image "orpheus-iaas" replaced
image "orpheus-proxy" replaced
image "orpheus-tenant-mgmt" replaced
image "orpheus-ui-basic" replaced
image "orpheus-ui-connections" replaced
image "orpheus-ui-instances" replaced
image "orpheus-ui-templates" replaced
image "provider-terraform-local" replaced
```

Answer (score 1):

When loading the CAM PPA package into ICP, I did not include the `--namespace services` as indicated in the CAM installation topic: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2L37/cam_installing_cam.html

I was able to use the workaround of changing all of the CAM images scope to `global`:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0/manage_images/change_scope.html

I deleted the existing CAM deploy and then attempted the deploy again successfully.